# getting error in JS as :"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" while executing below code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting the :"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" while calling the delete function inside the creteHtmlview function.

````
            console.log("Delete Item is being called")
            
        }
        //View layers

        function createHtmlListView ( { amount,SpentDate,desc} ) {
            //console.log(SpentDate.valueOf())
            return `
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                            ${desc}
                            <small class="text-muted">${SpentDate}</small>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="px-5">
                                ${amount}
                            </span>
                            <button 
                                id="deleteOnClick"
                                type="button" 
                                class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                                onclick="deleteItem(${SpentDate})"
                                >
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </li>`

           }```
````

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SpentDate` is a string, it needs to be quoted.

```
   onclick="deleteItem('${SpentDate}')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

I have injected the Html you are creating in js file into a `div.main` just to verify
the **Delete** button is working. On click see console.

Also I have included bootstrap.css. Remove it if you dont want.

**Working Code**

```js
function createHtmlListView({
  amount,
  SpentDate,
  desc
}) {

  return `
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                            ${desc}
                            <small class="text-muted">${SpentDate}</small>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="px-5">
                                ${amount}
                            </span>
                            <button 
                                id="deleteOnClick"
                                type="button" 
                                class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                                onclick="deleteItem('${SpentDate}')"
                                >Delete
                                <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </li>`

};

function deleteItem(date) {
  console.log(`Deleting item with date : ${date}`);
}


document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = createHtmlListView({
  amount: '$100',
  SpentDate: '26 Sept 2020',
  desc: "Product Description"
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main" id="main">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should remove three backtick characters (`) on the last line of code

Code should be look like this

```
function createHtmlListView({ amount, SpentDate, desc }) {
  //console.log(SpentDate.valueOf())
  return `
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
              <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                  ${desc}
                  <small class="text-muted">${SpentDate}</small>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <span class="px-5">
                      ${amount}
                  </span>
                  <button 
                      id="deleteOnClick"
                      type="button" 
                      class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                      onclick="deleteItem(${SpentDate})"
                      >
                      <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </li>`;
}
```